# How to remove White space on a image border - CSS

Tags: html, css

Helo guys, im getting a weird white space on a border box. I have already try apply the next examples:

```css
.blogPost1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid #595959;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blogPost1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>Lorem consetetur sadipscing elitr.</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et</p>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Check if the image has a white line on the right

Comment: nop it doesnt, i export  the img from adobe xd.

Comment: use outline instead of border.

Comment: can i set radius on outilne property?

Answer (score 0):

you could try the css:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

maybe it has an effect for your case

Comment: i already have it on the css folder

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

Answer (score 0):

fully css rules

```
    html{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

body{
    margin:0;
}

/* NavBar */
.navbar{    
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #595959;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.firstLogo{
    position: relative;
    right: 15em;
}
.midleNav1{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    right: 1.6em;

}
.midleNav1 a{
padding: 1em;
text-transform: uppercase;

}

.socialIcons{
    position: relative;
    left: 15em;
}
.socialIcons  a{
    padding: 0.1em;
}

/* Hero Section */


.container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    
    
}

.container::before{
    content:"";
    background-image: url(/images/heroImg.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9em;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 512px;
    opacity: 17%;
}
.hero{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hero h1{
    position: relative;
    color: #595959;
    width: 13em;
    font-size: 2.4em; 
    left: 1em;
}

.hero h6{
    color: #595959;
    opacity: 70%;
    position: relative;
    left: 8.8em;
    bottom: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

.hero button{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    right: 2.5em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E76F51;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.479) ;
}


/* GRID SECTION*/


.grid{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "first second"
        "third fourth"
    ;
}

.first{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
grid-area: first;
background-color: #E76F51;
padding: 4em;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.first svg{
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: 0.6em;
}

.second{
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
grid-area: second;
background-color: white;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
color: #595959;
}

.second svg{
    width: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.second h1{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.second  h3{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 18em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}


.third{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    grid-area: third;
    background-color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #595959;
}
.third svg{
    width: 5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.third h1{
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.third  h3{
    width: 20em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}


.fourth{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    grid-area: fourth;
    background-color: #2A9D8F;
    padding: 4em;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.fourth svg{
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: 0.6em;
}


/* Sentence */

.sentence{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 60%;
}


/* BLOG POST */

.blogTitle{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}

.blogBox{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(12em ,25%));
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    gap: 1em;
    padding: 0 5em 0 5em;
}

.blogPost1{
    grid-column: 1/3;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    /* outline: 1px solid #595959; */
}

.blogPost2{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    
}
.blogPost3{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    
}
.blogPost4{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    
}
.blogPost5{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
}

.blogPost6{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
}

.blogPost7{
    /* display: flex;
    flex-flow: column; */
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
}
.blogBox h1{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.blogBox p{
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

the snippet have white space if you did not saw, maybe your lcd have bad resolution.

[image]

Comment: i see the white space on your image but on my snippet I see no white space

Comment: I update my snippet to include all your css.  now how about the html that goes with it?  Again, I see no white space

Comment: do you want to do a chat to see if we can get to the bottom of this?